# Перенос текста предложения на новую строку без наличия пробела

Tags: html, css, текст, перенос-слов

значит задача такая, word-wrap сразу отлетает ибо он переносит строку в любом случае как только сообщение дойдет до конца блока, мне это не нужно если пользователь пишет комментарий с наличием пробелов, ибо тогда он сам переносится, но есть пользователи которые любят поспамить буквами в одну строку и тогда уже их надо перебрасывать, вопрос - как оставить перенос строки с наличием пробелов(перенос логично же через пробел) и перебрасывать его жестче(т.е перенося буквы) если их там нет.

для тех кто не понял пример -------------------- див заканчивается вот тут -

Я - о всем привет как у вас дела сегодня хороший день да конечно

а еще у меня отлично настроение

Второй я - АААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААА

АААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААА

Comment: Не проще ли регуляркой сокращать такие непотребства? Например, не более 5 одинаковых символов подряд, пробелы при этом не затрагивать.

Comment: Согласен с предыдущим оратором. Можно в JS перед выводом или на сервере сделать регулярку, заменяющую каждый длинный кусок на короткие, вставляя в разрывы не пробел, а `&shy;` , тогда вообще не будет виден разрыв, а в нужных местах будут переносы с тире.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev: Вы согласны со мной, а я с Вами - вылетел что-то из головы мягкий перенос.

Comment: можно узнать а как реализовать проверку на длину для каждого слова в предложении